# Differentiating logarithms

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

I am trying to prove that $$
f(x) = ^alog(x) => f'(x) = \frac {1} {ln(a)*x}
$$

So I start at$$
f(x) = ^alog(x)
$$

Then I move to:$$
f(x) =\frac {ln(x)} {ln(a)}
$$

And there I get stuck: I want to use the quotient rule, but the entire internet tells me to use the chain rule. And indeed, with the quotient rule I get stuck on an island far away. But still: to me this looks a lot more like:$$
f(x) = \frac {g(x)} {h(x)}
$$
Then$$
f(x) = g(h(x))
$$

So why do I need to use the chain rule from here? How can I use it in this situation?

Comment: $1/\ln a$ is a constant. Use the constant multiple rule: $\bigl(Cf(x)\bigr)'=cf'(x)$.

Comment: Incidentally, I think you meant to say "quotient rule" not "quotation rule".

Comment: Yep, fixed. Thank you=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for the quotient rule: $\dfrac 1{\ln (a)}$ is a constant.

$$
f(x) =\frac {\ln(x)} {\ln(a)} = \frac 1{\ln(a)}\cdot \ln(x) \implies f'(x) = \dfrac{1}{\ln (a)}\cdot \frac 1x = \frac{1}{\ln(a)x}
$$